# Why is source speed different from RStudio console line code?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a script with self-written functions (no plots). When I copy-paste that script into the R-Studio console, it takes ages to execute, but when I use `source("Helperfunctions.R")` it doesn't take more than a second.

## Question: Where does the difference in speed come from?

I am aware of two differences between running code via the `source()` function vs. entering code at the R-Studio console:

From `?source`:

> Since expressions are not executed at the top level, auto-printing is not done.

The way I understand this: `source()` will *not* plot graphs (unless made specific with e.g. `print(plot)`), while the R Studio console codes *will* always plot graphs. I'm sure this will affect the speed of execution to a certain degree, but this seems irrelevant in my case, because there are barely any plot calls.

And:

> (...) the complete file is parsed before any of it is run

I have been working with `R` for a while now, but I'm not sure whether this relevant for the speed-issue I'm having. Is it possible that completely parsing all code "before any of it is run" speeds up the execution of my helper functions script by a factor of a hundred?

**Edit**: I'm using R version 3.2.3.

Comment: R must parse your code regardless if you source it all at once or if you do it line by line. Are you using Rgui? What exactly takes long?

Comment: I use RStudio. I always start my scripts with `source("Helperfunctions.R")`, this is quick. However, when I copy the content of Helperfunctions.R and execute the code directly, it takes ages for the code to run. Does that help, @Roland ?

Comment: I've observed the same and don't know the reason. I think there is even something about it in the RStudio support forums.

Comment: Do you observe the same performance degradation when you paste your commands in a plain `R` shell? If no, then this is definitely RStudio (where I also observed performance issues executing lines of code from the editor).

Comment: @MartinNyolt @Roland the `R` shell is certainly much (!!) faster than RStudio. Please post it as a solution. Any chance there is a simple answer as to why RStudio is so slow in this case? Are there cases in which RStudio is actually faster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is not `source()` vs. console line code. Instead, it is an issue of how RStudio sends code from the source pane to the console.

When I copy the content of `Helperfunctions.R` and run it in RGui (instead of RStudio), the code is executed with nearly the same speed as when I use `source("Helperfunctions.R")` in RStudio.

Apparently, lines of code always (?) require more execution time in RStudio than in RGui. Even though you may usually not notice the time-difference when executing a couple of lines in the console, it seems to make a huge difference when, say, 3.000 lines of code are being executed in the R Studio console at once.

My understanding is that upon using `source("Helperfunctions.R")` in the RStudio source pane, the code is not actually sent to the RStudio console (which would have been slow), but is actually executed directly in the `R` language.

Comment: It's interesting but has it been confirmed by the folks at Rstudio? I understand the extra layer but it shouldn't make such a difference.